# What is the fast way to concatenate strings in VBScript

Tags: string, performance, concatenation

The string concatenation time is  almost the exponential function of the amount concatenations and the total size of the target string due to memory relocation each time when there is a statement like
     **myStr= myStr+anotherString**

Answer (score 0):

The string concatenation time is almost the exponential function of the amount concatenations and the total size of the target string due to memory relocation each time when there is a statement like

```
**myStr= myStr+anotherString**
```

The code below was based on the idea taken from
http://nerds-central.blogspot.com/2007/04/high-speed-string-concatenation-in-100.html?m=1.

The idea is to use one-directional linked list of objects to prevent expensive memory reallocation.
I optimized the code for a quite large amount of concatenations to reduce the number of elements in the list since excessive numbers caused crashes in IIS.

The use case is concatenating multiple times then get the resulting string
In my testing it was able to concatenate over 10000 string totaling 25 MB

```
 'Example of use:
 dim str="Quite a long-long-long-long-long-long-long string here"
 dim oStr,resultString
 set oStr= new FStringCat        
    for i= 1 to 100000
            oStr.Add(str)             
     Next
 resultString = oStr.ToString()  ' this will take some time
 

 '====================================
class FStringCat
    private sp
    private ep
    private l
    private accum
    private  maxLen
    private objCount
    private  bigString   
    private switched
    public Length
    private sub Class_Initialize
        l=0
        accum=""
        set sp=nothing
        Length=0
        maxLen=2800
        objCount=0
    end sub
    
    public sub Add(what)
        Length=Length+len(what)
        if switched then
             bigString.Add(what)
             exit sub
        end if
   
        if objCount>1200  then  ' prevent IIS crash
            set bigString=new FastStringHV
            bigString.Add(accum)
            bigString.Add(what)
            switched=true
            exit sub
        end if
       
        accum=accum & what
    
        if len(accum)> maxLen then   ' originally 2800
            objCount=objCount+1
            if objCount>1000 then
                maxLen=15000
                if(sp is nothing) then
                    set ep=new XLink
                    set sp=ep
                else
                    dim oep
                    set oep=ep
                    set ep=new XLink
                    set oep.nextXLink=ep
                end if
                ep.datum=accum
                accum=""
                l=l+1
            end if
        end if
    end sub

    public function ToString()
        if l=0 then
            toString=accum
            exit function
        end if
        ep.datum=ep.datum & accum
    
        while l>1 
            dim ptr:     set ptr=sp
            dim nsp :   set nsp=new XLink
            dim nep :     set nep=nsp
            dim nl :     nl=0
        
            while not (ptr is nothing) 
                if  nep.datum=""  then
                    nep.datum=ptr.datum
                    nl=nl+1
                else
                    if ptr.datum<>"" then nep.datum=nep.datum & ptr.datum
                    set nep.nextXLink=new XLink
                    set nep=nep.nextXLink
                end if
                set ptr=ptr.nextXLink
            wend
            set sp=nsp
            set ep=nep
            l=nl
        wend
        if  switched then
            ToString=sp.datum +bigString.ToString()
        else
            ToString=sp.datum 
        end if
    end function
end class

class XLink
    public datum
    public nextXLink
    private sub Class_Initialize
        set nextXLink=nothing
        datum=""
    end sub
end class


'HV 
class FastStringHV
    private longStr
    private str

    private sub Class_Initialize
        str=""
        longStr=""
    end sub

    public sub Add(what)
        if len(str) > 2800 then
            longStr=longStr+str
            str=""
        end if
        str=str+what
    end sub 

    public function ToString()
        if len(longStr) = 0 then
            ToString=str
        elseif len(str)=0 then
            ToString=longStr
        else
            ToString=longStr+str
        end if
    end function

end class
```